# How to initialize or get the collection of objects of a class in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, collections, xamarin.android

I am trying to get the list of installed applications from Package Manager.
I don't know how to initialize or get the list. It must be simple but I am just missing a link or a step.

```
List<PackageInfo> packageInfo = PackageManager
                  .GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
```

Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

You need a simple Conversion operator at the end.

```
List<PackageInfo> packageInfo = PackageManager
                  .GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData) as List<PackageInfo>;
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I know how I could also cast `List`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs you may stick with `IList`

```
IList<PackageInfo> packageInfo = PackageManager
    .GetInstalledPackages(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
```

If you actually need an instance of `List` call `ToList` (requires `using System.Linq;`)

```
List<PackageInfo> packageInfo = PackageManager
    .GetInstalledPackages(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Would casting it to `List<PackageInfo>` be more performant compared to calling `ToList()`?

Comment: @S.tenBrinke if `GetInstalledApplications` returns an actual `List` instance then `ToList` call won't iterate though collection and will perform array copying which is pretty fast, but yes it is more performant to cast in this case. But if `GetInstalledApplications` returns anything else impementing `IList` interface but it is not `List` then `ToList` will create `List` instance and cast will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Would using `var packageInfo` instead of `List<PackageInfo>` suit your needs? @mtv 's answer could also work but I think using var is better for performance and readablility

Comment: I find out `IList` when I was debugging with `var` declaration. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `var` does work.

Actually there was wrong class. It should be `ApplicationInfo` class.

So it is either

```
IList<ApplicationInfo> packageInfo = PackageManager
    .GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
```

or

```
var packageList = PackageManager 
    .GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
```

Yes it should be `IList`. Thanks.

Comment: If I use `PackageManager.GetInstalledPackages(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);` then it will be `IList<PackageInfo>`.